# Errors after updating to Anroid 3.6.1

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin

Recently I updated my Android Studio into 3.6.1 without any problems occurring, but as soon as the Gradle finished syncing, an error message shows in my Build and Event Log.

---

(Inside the "Build" message)

- org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException:
  Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
- org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not
  resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.61.
- org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: No cached
  version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.61 available
  for offline mode.

(inside the "Event log")

Gradle sync failed: No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.61 available for offline mode.

---

I noticed that there's a "kotlin" (from the Event log) involved in the message, but I haven't used a single project with Kotlin yet.
I haven't seen any solutions that helped me so far, only saw old problems that were slightly the same as mine that's why I posted this question instead. Its the first time this error occurred to me, and also my first time asking a question.
Right now, I'm not able to run any of my projects in Android Studio because of this error. Please help!

-Thank you for answering in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check and disable the offline gradle and try again, Android Studio is muture enough to solve most of the problems now days. Try again after enabling the online gradle and click on sync again(eleghant icon with down arrow) to left of AVD icon in toolbar.

[image]

Comment: Oh yes that worked for me! Thank you so much! Although I am curious as to why my Gradle is toggled to offline mode? I did not change anything on that part before.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling android sdk maybe the problem is solved.